# Failed review of question

Tags: discussion, review-queues, disputed-review-audits

I've failed reviewing this question [Is there a safe way to download the java JDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911615/is-there-a-safe-way-to-download-the-java-jdk)

I thought the question should be moved to SuperUser - even though it is about downloading a programming tool, it seems to me it is more of a browsing/networking general usage, not about programming.

Can anyone please clarify why I am wrong?

UPDATE:

It looks like the question was closed after all, with suggestions to move it to SuperUser. I still got stuck with the failed audit, though.

Comment: What was the actual review?

Comment: @Cerbrus: http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/6883010

Comment: You reviewed this triage item as _"Unsalvageable"_. That really doesn't apply to a well-worded question that may need to be moved.

Comment: Yes, by reviewing as Unsalvageable you get the option to suggest moving the question to SuperUser.

Comment: This looks like ot/rec-link to me, at least given the title. Can anyone confirm?